# ts:How to access the state inside redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

My collection of reducers are stored into rootReducer (has normal reducer and slice reducer).

I need to access the state inside those reducers with useSelector hook.

My store :

```
const store = configureStore({reducer : rootReducer});
```

RootReducer:

```
const reducers = {
  getName,
  getSomething,
  getCollection,
  getSomethingelse
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
```

Sample Reducers(createSlice):

```
const initialState:any = {
    nameList:[]
}

const setNameList = createSlice({
    name:"setNameList",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        setNameList(state,action){
            state.nameList.push(action.payload);
        }
    }
});
```

Another Sample Reducer (normal):

```
export default function somethingReducer(state = {
    something:{}
}, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case C.SOMETHING_ZONE:{        
            return {
                ...state
                ,something :action.payload
            }
        }
        default : {}
    }
    return state
}
```

I tried to do,

```
  const name = useSelector(state => state.getName.nameList)
  const something = useSelector(state => state.getSomething.something)
```

But got an error : `Property 'getName' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.`

Answer (score 2):

There is problem in your RootReducer. Change the const variable following way:

```
const reducers = {
  getName: setNameList.reducer,
  getSomething: somethingReducer.reducer  
}
```

Do not forget to import the reducer and use the other reducer same way.